# Can powerup powercores be combined?

Tags: colossatron

Can Shield, Rapid Fire or Nuclear Warhead powercores be combined?  If I put three of the same kind together, will their armour and powers increase?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the base powercores together in almost any combination:

Red and Yellow to make Orange
Red and Blue to make Purple
Blue and Yellow to make green

However you cannot add orange to green or purple as they are in their final state.

Neither can you add nukes to each other to make a bigger nuke or better shield or faster rapid fire.